# What is the use of the term 'all-nighter'?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

Well I know: 'all nigh long' but how just add 'er' to the word 'night' and add an extra "all-" before it, gives it some kind of sense? I mean as far as i kown the 'er' added to the noun makes it an action performer of that noun, right?

Comment: Suffix ***-er*** (and ***-or***) very often denote *performer* of the activity represented by the "main" word (be it a NOUN, as in ***mouser*** for a cat who catches mice, or a VERB, as in ***writer*** for a person who writes). But usually, the specific term ***all-nighter*** would refer to *an **event or activity** that continues throughout the night*, rather than ***a person doing*** something all night long. [It's in the dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all-nighter) with that meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As Fumble commented, "all-nighter" is a noun meaning *something that lasts all night long*. I'm my experience (in America) it is almost exclusively used to mean **a study session** (or similar event, such as writing a paper) that takes so long the person doing it is not able to get any sleep at all before starting their next day. In this usage it takes the verb **pull**: "I pulled an all-nighter last night" or "I haven't even started writing that yet, I'll have to pull an all-nighter to get it done in time."

It can be used for other activities, like playing video games or maybe researching/tinkering on an invention, but the most common usage is studying for an exam or working on an assignment. An **event** that is scheduled to last all night would probably be described as "an all-night concert" (or whatever) rather than "an all-nighter."